# Eclipse not able to create gradle Project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am trying to create a gradle Project in Eclipse. Gradle ist 100% installed and the system environment variables are set correctly. Before I create the project in Eclipse, I get the option to set the paths of gradle as you can see in the following image

[image]

It doesn't make any difference what box I check, what path i put in or even if I just let it completely empty. I always get the following error when eclipse try to create the project in the following step

[image]

I am pretty sure that's because the Gradle user Home is not set anymore as you can see at the top.

But the question here is how to fix that...

Thanks in advance and sorry again for my trash English

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow  Would you mind copying the exception that's shown in the last screenshot into the question? That will help tremendously. Also, which version of Eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the latest gradle version was selected. The version was 8.4 rc.

I changed that to the stable version, 8.3, and things worked.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you scroll down the error message text area, then you'll eventually find this message:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 61

1 error

    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileScript(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:139)
    ... 154 more
```

It fails because Gradle `6.9.1` is not compatible with Java 17. The first Gradle version supporting Java 17 will be Gradle `7.3`. You may want to keep an eye on the [Gradle Compatibility Matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html).

That being said, when using Gradle `6.9.1` you can use Java up to version 15. Gralde `7.2` supports Java 16.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've not found out what the problem was but I've found out how to surround it.
I just reinstalled a newer version of gradle. And also I didn't click the same download button as I did before. I don't know if that could be an issue maybe with the download file of gradle

[image]

Comment: I have suggested this link  same answer:  https://gradle.org/install/